# How to execute one test case multiple time in parallel in Robot framework?

Tags: automated-testing, robotframework

I want to execute one test case multiple times in parallel, for example, execute test_case1 10 times concurrently?
I am not able to achieve this using pabot --processes

Comment: Welcome. I'd expect a bit more information in your question. How do you know the test case is not executed in parallel? Do you get any error? If so, post it in your question as well.

Comment: Because it's only executing a single test case.

Comment: That's hardly an answer to my questions. Anyway, if you need a serious answer, you need to add more information. We don't have your context and don't see your screen and other outputs.

Comment: Have you tried --include {tag} {tag} {tag}  or -t "*Your test case name*" . . .

Comment: the test get executed as much time the tag or '.' is repeated

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
pabot --processes 8 -d results -o Output.xml Tests --include {tag} {tag} {tag}
```

Or

```
pabot --processes 8 -d results -o Output.xml Tests  -t "Your test case name" . . .
```

You could also use argument file to achieve what you want.

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Pabot executed the suite multiple times, but not in parallel, even if --processes was defined. All tests were executed serialized